# jquery datepicker does not set date in ASP.net gridview EditItemTemplate and FooterTemplate's textBox

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, .net, asp.net

I am trying to implement a VERY simple ASP.net page: A GridView that allows user to edit old entry or insert a new entry. One of the columns in the GridView is holiday, so I use Jquery's datepicker to allow user to select a date.

Here is the ASP.net code

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Height="300px"
                ShowFooter="True"           
                AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting" 
                OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing"
                OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating"
                OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit"
                OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" > 

            <Columns> 

 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date">
               <EditItemTemplate> 
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtEditDate" runat="server" Text='<%# GetDate(Eval("CAL_DT")) %>' OnLoad="DisplayDatePicker1" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox> 
               </EditItemTemplate>
               <FooterTemplate> 
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtNewDate"  runat="server"  OnLoad="DisplayDatePicker2" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
               </FooterTemplate> 
               <ItemTemplate> 
                    <asp:Label ID="lblDate" runat="server" Text='<%# GetDate(Eval("CAL_DT")) %>'></asp:Label>  
               </ItemTemplate> 
            </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit" ShowHeader="False"> 
            <EditItemTemplate> 
              <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Update" Text="Update"></asp:LinkButton> 
              <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel"></asp:LinkButton> 
            </EditItemTemplate> 
            <FooterTemplate> 
              <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="AddNew" Text="Add New"></asp:LinkButton> 
            </FooterTemplate> 
            <ItemTemplate> 
              <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit"></asp:LinkButton> 
            </ItemTemplate> 
        </asp:TemplateField> 
           </Columns>           
          </asp:GridView>
```

Here is my DisplayDatePicker1 method, DisplayDatePicker2 would be very similar.

```
protected void DisplayDatePicker1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StringBuilder scriptText = new StringBuilder();
    string clientID = (sender as TextBox).ClientID;
    scriptText.Append("$(function() {");
    scriptText.Append("var DateSelector1 = $('#" + clientID + "'); ");
    scriptText.Append("DateSelector1.datepicker();");
    scriptText.Append(" });");
    this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(),
                   "DateScript1", scriptText.ToString(), true); 
}
```

So far so good. User can see the popup Datepicker and pick a date when he/she clicks Edit in the GridView row. Howerver, The following is the problem

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox txtEditHoliday = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtEditHoliday");
    TextBox txtEditDate = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtEditDate");
    DropDownList dpdCountry = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("dpdCountry");

    //txtEditDate.Text is not set,
}
```

txtEditDate.Text still contains the **old date**.  The value selected by user via JQuery datepicker is not being passed to the txtEditDate.Text   Please help!  I spent many hours to search the internet but have not found any solutions.

Comment: Did you check the e.NewValues to see if that has updated value?

Comment: Why are you injecting the javascript/jquery code into the page?  You can put it in the markup...put a cssclass on each textbox that will get the datepicker assigned and use that as the selection criteria.

Comment: check id of textbox while rendering it as the attached pages with masterpage there id changed on runtime something like "ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1....".

Comment: When are you DataBinding the gridview? show me the point at which you databind. You could be doing so in PageLoad (not in !IsPostback block)

Answer (score 1):

To get the new, revised values - use :

```
e.NewValues
```

(from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewupdateeventargs.aspx)